# how to define eventEmitter properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, eventemitter

I need to define a helper object in which I need a function that will execute on each "orientationchange" event of window.

My code as below and it is not in correct form. Can you please help me how can I define onRotate properly so that I can use it globally.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    var GlobalHelper = (function () {

        var me = {
            onRotate: onRotate // this is where I am struggling
        }

        function onRotate() {
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function (event) {
                console.log(event.target.screen.orientation.angle);
            });
        }

        return me;

    })();

    GlobalHelper.onRotate = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my own question. It was actually pretty easy.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    var GlobalHelper = (function () {

        var me = {
            onRotate: function (e) {  }
        }

        function _init() {
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function (event) {
                me.onRotate(event);
            });
        }

        _init();

        return me;

    })();

    GlobalHelper.onRotate = function (e) {
       console.log(e);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to add custom programmable method for creating listeners and bonded functions. You can test it by Running code snippet and pressing keyboard keys while focused on results window.

```js
// Set app object
const bindFn = e => {
  // Set object to hold your functions
  let fns = {};
  
  // Set event listener to run all functions in fns object
  window.addEventListener(e, event => {
    for(const f in fns) fns[f](event);
  });
  
  // Return method to set new functions
  // You can extend it with another function for
  // deleting or altering, as you wish...
  return {
    add: (name, fn) => {
      if(!fns[name]) fns[name] = fn;
      else console.log(`Function with name ${name} already exist, skipping...`);
    }
  };
};

// Set binder with proper event
// here we do orientation change
const OrCh = bindFn("orientationchange");

// Add some function to execute on this event
OrCh.add('log', event => console.log(event.target.screen.orientation.angle));

//
// Test with another event that easy to trigger on stackoverflow
const KeyP = bindFn("keypress");

// Add logger
KeyP.add('log', event => console.log(`key pressed: ${event.code}`));

// Add something else
KeyP.add('logAlt', event => console.log(`Alternative function: ${event.code}`));
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will study this code to improve mine.